# when i input a char,mainthread and child thread all return?

Tags: multithreading, getchar

//see thd code.why child will and process,c = NULL?

```
void* process(void* arg){
  char c = getchar();
  printf("process,c = %c\n",c);
}
int main()
{
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,process,NULL);
  char c = getchar();
  printf("main,c = %c\n",c);
  pthread_join(tid,NULL);
  printf("over\n");
  return 0;
}
```

//and main,c has value,and process,c not have value

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` only returns each character of input only once. You have two threads that both call `getchar()`. When a character arrives, one of them returns that character while the other thread waits for the next character.

Comment: I think you are wrong,maybe you can run my code,when I test above demo ,I found mu thought it's wrong

Comment: I ran your code. I don't see any NULLs. In my two tests, the main thread got the first input character and the thread read the second character. However, I guess another order is possible as well.